# Get rid of "csc-frame" div wrap in TYPO3

Tags: typo3, typoscript

Here is my code:

```
    lib.navigation{
         10 = RECORDS
            10 {
                 source = uid
                 tables = tt_content
            }
    }
```

Here I'm just creating a menu through content element and I wanted to remove the default div with class=csc-frame csc-frame-frame1 from the rendered content

I used like this:

```
lib.navigation{
     10 = RECORDS
        10 {
             conf.tt_content.stdWrap.innerWrap.cObject.default = TEXT
             source = uid
             tables = tt_content
        }
}
```

but this will remove only csc_default div.

Comment: I don't understand why the css_styled_content default classes are added when using RECORDS. In my opinion they might come from elsewhere, not from the TS above. I prefer to use CONTENT objects to extract special content and format the precisely via renderObj. See this link: http://www.typo3wizard.com/en/articles/explaining-the-content-object.html

Answer (score 1):

This might do the trick. Make sure to include it before the navigation definition.

```
tt_content.stdWrap.innerWrap.cObject.default >
```